# Java - How do I save a complex object (non-Serializable) to a file?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

I am trying to save the following object to a file for later use:

```
public class Templates implements Serializable {

    private List<ReportTemplate> sources;
    private List<ReportTemplate> destinations;

    public List<ReportTemplate> getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    public void setSources(List<ReportTemplate> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    public List<ReportTemplate> getDestinations() {
        return destinations;
    }

    public void setDestinations(List<ReportTemplate> destinations) {
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }

}
```

However, the `ReportTemplate` class contains `SimpleStringProperty` and `SimpleObjectProperty` fields. The `SimpleObjectProperty` holds a custom object that also contains `Property` fields.

I have all classes implementing `Serializable` but, obviously, the property fields are not, leading to many errors when trying to serialize `Templates`.

What workarounds can I do here? I also looked into saving as XML using the `JAXB` API, but run into similar issues.

I have spent the past hour or so reading up on various questions regarding serializing non-serializable objects, but they all only go one level deep; as in, they talk about serializing a non-serializable `String`, but not custom objects that also have non-serializable fields.

If there is a better way to save an object like this other than Serialization or XML, I am definitely open to suggestions; I just need to be able to write/read this object.

**EDIT:**
Per Vinoth's answer, I tried Gson with mixed results. Everything works fine when serializing the `Templates` object in a simple test, but when using it in my application, I get the following exceptions when trying to load the object again after writing it:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper<java.lang.String>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Abstract class can't be instantiated! Class name: com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper
```

The output Json adds "helper" and "observable" keys for some reason, only in the actual application, not the tests.

The `Templates` object contains `ArrayLists` of the `ReportTemplate` objects, but nothing is observable.

The objects in the test and my application are identical, so I don't know why it's getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

use Gson (https://github.com/google/gson)
toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON  String.  you can save json string into xml

Serialisation:

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String  templateJson=gson.toJson(templateObj);
```

Deserialisation:

```
String templateJson="{.....}"
Templates template = gson.fromJson(templateJson, Templates.class);
```

Comment: I have been trying to use Gson since seeing your answer and have only had minor success. The `toJson()` and `fromJson()` work fine in a simple test, but in my actual application, the `toJson()` adds "helper" and "observable" keys to the output. This causes an exception when trying to load the file again, as it is trying to instantiate `com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper', which is an abstract class.

Comment: @Zephyr, did you ever figure out a solution? I am pretty much in the same boat.

Comment: @A.J. - No, I haven't; ended up using a completely different approach for now.